# ng-view on DOM elements not sharing a close parent

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ng-view

Is there a way for ng-view to bind two DOM elements that don't share a common *close* parent ?

My understanding of ng-view is that it binds a DOM element to dynamically switch between templates (which further generate views). What happens if I have, say, a search bar and a label that have very low "proximity" in the box model sense, but that architecturally should be bound to the same controller ?

Is there a way around this other than forcing same-controller elements to share a common parent and resort to *usually* bad CSS styling practices ?

Answer (score 0):

You description is very general so I can't give you a specific solution, but you have 2 obvious options here:
1) You can wrap your whole good practiced CSS page in a div that is the ng-view itself.  That's not a bad habit actually.  Just make the "body" bound to the controller (or wrap your whole page in `<div id="wrapper">` and then do with CSS and HTML whatever you like
2) You can use angular-ui which enables multiple views on the same page. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views